# How to skip a specific row in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database which looks like:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| ProductName | Status  | Branch |
+-------------+---------+--------+
| P1          | dead    |      1 |
| P1          | dead    |      2 |
| P2          | expired |      1 |
| P3          | expired |      3 |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

I want to show the result after comparison of products as:(Comparing products from Branch 1 and 2)

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| ProductName | Branch 1|Branch 2|
+-------------+---------+--------+
| P1          | dead    |    dead|
| P2          | expired |    OK  |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

But after I run the following query:

```
<pre>
SELECT  ProductName,
MAX(CASE 
WHEN Branch=1 
THEN Status
ELSE NULL 
END) AS 'Branch 1',
MAX(CASE 
WHEN Branch=2
THEN Status
ELSE NULL 
END) AS 'Branch 2'
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY ProductName;
```

I get result as:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| ProductName | Branch 1|Branch 2|
+-------------+---------+--------+
| P1          | dead    |    dead|
| P2          | expired |    OK  |
| P3          | OK      |    OK  |  
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200de/2)
What i want is not to include the products in the table which are other than that of Branch 1 or 2. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your query results using `WHERE Branch IN(1,2)`

```
SELECT  ProductName,
      COALESCE(  MAX(CASE 
            WHEN Branch=1 
            THEN Status
            ELSE NULL 
        END) ,'OK') AS 'Branch 1',
       COALESCE( MAX(CASE 
            WHEN Branch=2
            THEN Status
            ELSE NULL 
        END),'OK') AS 'Branch 2'
FROM    MyTable
WHERE Branch IN(1,2)
GROUP BY ProductName
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200de/3)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how exactly a **Where In** works?

Comment: `IN()` clause will include only rows whose branch is 1 or 2 it will filter all the rows having different branch number like 3, if you want to fetch records whose branch can b 2 or 3 then in clause will like `where Branch in(2,3)` see sample [`demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/200de/14)